# How to pass the entries using enter in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk

I'm learning programming with GTK, so I have a doubt... how can I jump from one entry to other ?

I'm with the cursor in the field "a", so I put a text in this field and pass to other without use TAB key.
there's a function, a signal to it ?

````
// I'm with the cursor in this entry below
    code_field = gtk_entry_new();
//so i want to press enter and jump to this
    name_field = gtk_entry_new();```
````

Comment: Do you mean something like this =>> https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=So56A_R_MZk&list=PLN_MPJUQgPVpkVVSJ8qrzk65FHnUtO6BF&index=37&t=0s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use g_signal_connect() with gtk_widget_grab_focus()

[g_signal_connect Documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gobject/gobject-Signals.html)

[gtk_widget_grab_focus Documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Widget.grab_focus.html)

#### Example:

assuming we have 3 variables, where you want change focus from entry1 to entry2 when enter is pressed on entry1.

```
GtkEntry *entry1;

GtkEntry *entry2;

void change_focus_func();
```

You should create an g_signal for the entry1, and connect it on change_focus_func, passing entry2 as 4º argument.

```
g_signal_connect(GTK_ENTRY(entry1),"activate",G_CALLBACK(change_focus_func),entry2);
```

Then function change_focus_func should be like:

```
void  change_focus_func(GtkWidget *Widget1, Widget2){
  gtk_widget_grab_focus(Widget2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set in which the order the widgets get the focus by calling [gtk_container_set_focus_chain](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-set-focus-chain) before GTK+ 3.24, and from 3.24 on, using the [`GtkWidget::focus`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-focus) signal. But normally GTK+ should compute a default order, so we'd need to know how you add these widgets to their container to determine why it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much I LL see it.